# Gmail Service In Google App Script is running slow every fourth operation. Why?

Tags: testing, google-apps-script, gmail, benchmarking

I was testing the Gmail Service on Google App Script, and i was wondering how fast will the taking of an email be. So I started executing this code:

```
// just a tester
function getInboxMails() {
  var execStart = new Date();

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var threadTime = new Date();

  logTime(execStart, threadTime, 'Get Thread Collection Time: ');

  var arrayThreads = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
     var thread = threads[i];
     var emails = getThreadEmails(thread);
     arrayThreads.push(emails);
  }

  var execEnd = new Date();

  logTime(execStart, execEnd, "Get Inbox Time: ");

  return arrayThreads;
}

function getThreadEmails(thread) {
  var execStart = new Date();
  var arrEmails = [];

  var count = thread.getMessageCount();
  var messages = thread.getMessages();

  var threadTime = new Date();

  logTime(execStart, threadTime, 'ta ' + thread.getId() + ': ');

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var message = messages[i];
    var mail = getEmailData(message);
    //arrEmails.push(mail);
  }

  var execEnd = new Date();
  //logTime(execStart, execEnd, 'Thread + data access: ');
  //Logger.log('\n');

  return arrEmails;
}

function getEmailData(message) {
  var execStart = new Date();
  var mail = {
    body : message.getBody(),
    to : message.getTo(),
    cc : message.getCc(),
    bcc : message.getBcc(),
    from : message.getFrom(),
    date : message.getDate(),
    plainBody : message.getPlainBody(),
    rawContent : message.getRawContent(),
    replyTo : message.getReplyTo(),
    subject : message.getSubject(),
    mailId : message.getId()
  }

  var execEnd = new Date();
  //Mail Access
  logTime(execStart, execEnd, 'ma ' + mail.mailId + ': ');

  return mail;
}

function logTime(startDate, endDate, message) {
  var timeDiff = endDate - startDate;

  var ms = timeDiff % 1000;
  timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff/1000);

  var sec = timeDiff % 60;

  Logger.log(message + sec + '.' + ms); 
}
```

The result was:

```
    [14-05-19 10:28:10:334 EEST] Get Thread Collection Time: 0.513
    [14-05-19 10:28:10:591 EEST] ta 14608be50b3e2972: 0.256
    [14-05-19 10:28:10:924 EEST] ma 14608be50b3e2972: 0.333
    [14-05-19 10:28:11:088 EEST] ta 14605c88a55e1d5f: 0.164
    [14-05-19 10:28:15:238 EEST] ma 14605c88a55e1d5f: 4.150
    [14-05-19 10:28:15:398 EEST] ta 14604dcdc318938f: 0.159
    [14-05-19 10:28:15:539 EEST] ma 14604da59c36f292: 0.141
    [14-05-19 10:28:15:671 EEST] ma 14604da60bd7f36b: 0.132
    [14-05-19 10:28:19:804 EEST] ma 14604da7e8364ae5: 4.133
    [14-05-19 10:28:19:954 EEST] ma 14604db33c6f5b07: 0.150
    [14-05-19 10:28:20:173 EEST] ma 14604db667e2501b: 0.219
    [14-05-19 10:28:20:305 EEST] ma 14604dba5e63713d: 0.132
    [14-05-19 10:28:24:436 EEST] ma 14604dc033d71d9f: 4.131
    [14-05-19 10:28:24:567 EEST] ma 14604dc6750e659a: 0.130
    [14-05-19 10:28:24:698 EEST] ma 14604dc8722693e9: 0.131
    [14-05-19 10:28:24:831 EEST] ma 14604dcdc318938f: 0.132
    [14-05-19 10:28:30:984 EEST] ta 146004ab2a9c64ca: 6.152
    [14-05-19 10:28:31:139 EEST] ma 145ff996cf2f4c13: 0.155
    [14-05-19 10:28:31:273 EEST] ma 145ff9f561109a80: 0.134
    [14-05-19 10:28:31:423 EEST] ma 146004ab2a9c64ca: 0.150
    [14-05-19 10:28:35:723 EEST] ta 1460040acea62d23: 4.300
    [14-05-19 10:28:35:861 EEST] ma 1460034634bfe0bc: 0.137
    [14-05-19 10:28:35:998 EEST] ma 14600387e9ce077a: 0.137
    [14-05-19 10:28:36:134 EEST] ma 146003af12370540: 0.136
    [14-05-19 10:28:40:279 EEST] ma 146003c3050f55c4: 4.144
    [14-05-19 10:28:40:500 EEST] ma 146003ce0072e0cf: 0.221
    [14-05-19 10:28:40:649 EEST] ma 146003d45600fb6c: 0.149
    [14-05-19 10:28:40:804 EEST] ma 146003da4c9592ee: 0.155
    [14-05-19 10:28:45:031 EEST] ma 14600405e2339b2b: 4.227
    [14-05-19 10:28:45:158 EEST] ta 145ff1ec0e9093bc: 0.125
    [14-05-19 10:28:45:292 EEST] ma 145ff1ec0e9093bc: 0.134
    [14-05-19 10:28:45:420 EEST] ta 145faac214352a74: 0.128
    [14-05-19 10:28:49:556 EEST] ma 145faa9301567f73: 4.136
    [14-05-19 10:28:49:681 EEST] ma 145faac214352a74: 0.124
    [14-05-19 10:28:49:806 EEST] ta 145faa6f9dd8fc04: 0.125
    [14-05-19 10:28:49:938 EEST] ma 145faa6f9dd8fc04: 0.132
    [14-05-19 10:28:56:131 EEST] ta 145fa9bbe29f0a9f: 6.192
    [14-05-19 10:28:56:282 EEST] ma 145fa9bbe29f0a9f: 0.151
    [14-05-19 10:28:56:405 EEST] ta 145fa98ea19a70d1: 0.123
    [14-05-19 10:28:56:541 EEST] ma 145fa98ea19a70d1: 0.135
    [14-05-19 10:29:00:674 EEST] ta 145fa940bac7a200: 4.133
    [14-05-19 10:29:00:802 EEST] ma 145fa940bac7a200: 0.128
    [14-05-19 10:29:00:930 EEST] ta 145fa940941fa6b7: 0.127
    [14-05-19 10:29:01:100 EEST] ma 145fa940941fa6b7: 0.169
    [14-05-19 10:29:05:227 EEST] ta 145fa9406e0239b3: 4.127
    [14-05-19 10:29:05:368 EEST] ma 145fa9406e0239b3: 0.141
    [14-05-19 10:29:05:369 EEST] Get Inbox Time: 55.547
```

As you can see the data access is very stable, but every fourth operation (first not included) is very slow. Like exactly four seconds slower (some times it is 6 but I guess that this can be predictable behavior also).

Can someone tell me why? And how can I avoid it?

Comment: I have the same question but I haven't found anything about this issue on the internet :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems that getPlainBody is like 10 times slower than getBody. I had a script that was taking ~90 seconds to execute. Switched getPlainBody out with getBody and it now takes ~10 seconds.